# How to select all records based on non-duplication of one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates

I just cannot seem to find an answer for this deceptively simple question. Most every solution either deletes all the duplicates, selects all the duplicates, or selects all the records except the duplicates. How can I select all rows such that, in this example, the "name" column values are unique, while selecting the first record of any duplicate set and ignoring the remaining duplicates of that same name? I do need all the values from all the columns in all the records in the selected record set.

```
Given the set of records:
   pk fk    name  secs  note
   1  100   cat   90    gray
   2  111   dog   123   mix
   3  233   fish  75    gold
   4  334   dog   932   black
   5  238   cow   90    stray
   6  285   cat   90    stray

The returned set should be:
   pk fk    name  secs  note
   1  100   cat   90    gray
   2  111   dog   123   mix
   3  233   fish  75    gold
   5  238   cow   90    stray

-- SQL
drop table if exists foo;
create table foo (
   pk int unsigned,
   fk int unsigned,
   name  varchar(10),
   secs  int,
   note  varchar(10),
primary key (pk)
) engine=innodb  default charset=utf8;

insert into foo
(pk, fk, name, secs, note)
values
   (1, 100, 'cat', 90, 'gray'),
   (2, 111, 'dog', 123, 'mix'),
   (3, 233, 'fish', 75, 'gold'),
   (4, 334, 'dog', 932, 'black'),
   (5, 238, 'cow', 90, 'stray'),
   (6, 285, 'cat', 90, 'stray');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that that returns what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  F.*
FROM
  foo F
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT
   MIN(F2.pk) AS `pk`
   ,F2.name
 FROM foo F2
 GROUP BY F2.name
) T 
ON T.pk = F.pk;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for editing my answer @hd1, the format options are not available when answering from my iPhone :-(

Comment: This is perfect! The MIN() function was the key here that I had not yet considered.  This particular pattern also preserves the record ordering and can and will be used as a sub-query in a larger UPDATE with SELECT statement. Thanks!

Comment: It's a pleasure to see that my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :

```
select * from table group by name;
```

Which can be written using distinct keyword as :

```
select distinct on name * from table;
```

Comment: The first suggestion is risky in the general context of aggregate function. I just so happens to work in MySQL-land, but in general the values returned in the non-aggregated columns are non-deterministic. Here is a good quick read: http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/.

Comment: The second query will tend to reorder records based on all the columns following the DISTINCT keyword and would be unsuitable for my purposes. However, I do appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 In SQL it will be


 select pk, fk, name, secs, note 
    from (select row_number() 
          over(partition by name order by pk) as rn,* 
          from foo) as tbl 
    where rn=1
```

Comment: try mentioning something in words too....straight queries dont generally help in terms of an answer!! :)

Comment: You should mentioned that in any other other DB except for MySQL you can use this. Unfortunately it will not work in MySQL